# How to stop objects moving on the same path in Corona sdk

Tags: android, iphone, lua, coronasdk

I have player and enemy objects on the scene. The enemies are generated randomly at the specified path, and the other one is player which is generated from the opposite side of enemy. I want to stop both these objects if they come some distance apart on the same path, and if any one of the two objects are destroyed by the firing then the other remaining object whether it must be enemy or player must start moving.

I have implemented below code, and it is working for the first time when they both are in front of each other and 200 distance apart. Suppose player fire the enemy then the enemy gets destroyed, and player starts moving but if now another enemy comes in front of the player then player does not stop, it keeps on moving, but the enemy stops. Please suggest some solution. Thanks...

```
for j=#enemy, 1, -1 do
  if(enemy[j].y~=nil and player.y~=nil then
   diff=player.y-enemy[j].y 
   if(enemy[j].x==player.x) then 
     if(diff<=200) then
       enemy[j].Speed=0
       player.speed=0
     end
   end
  else
  player.speed=-50
  enemy[j].Speed=2
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `player.speed=-50` for any `nil` `enemy[j].y`

Perhaps you should move the line

```
player.speed=-50
```

to above the `for` loop. That way, the player will move by default, but can be stopped by any enemy.